# No primary key vs Composite primary Key

Tags: sql, database-design

My scenario is to have a table for logging and reporting some important settings that users can change in a set of sites we maintain (each site has its own DB). When I was designing the table (going to be deployed on each DB), I was confused if I require a `Primary Key` or not. I have a column named `SiteID` and each row in the logging table will have `SiteId`, `newVal of Setting`, `oldVal of setting`, `Change date`. I will be using this to see the history of changes on a Site, filter changes by date etc. So in this scenario, obviously `SiteId` alone cannot be a `PK`, but do I really have to add a new column like `LogId` to make a composite `P`K ? Am I missing anything in here ?

Comment: If you add new columns to be a PK, it should not be composite PK. As the new columns is identify enough.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: I recommend always having a primary key.  In this case, an auto-incremented/identity column.

Comment: What is the advantage i am getting in this case of having the primary key ? I am not able to understand that point of why should I care about adding the PK in my scenario.

Comment: A table should **always** have a primary key - only with such a primary key can you **reliably and efficiently** identify each row in your table. And trust me - there will be plenty of cases when you **need to** be able to identify a single row clearly and efficiently

Comment: How do you know what setting a value is for? Is that part of the setting's value?

Comment: You seem to say "primary key" when you mean "surrogate key".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to focus on your use case.

If you can avoid data duplication (e.g. from the application side) and you know your data, and know what type of index etc. you need, you can easily avoid that; mainly if you talking about massive scans for reporting and when data duplication is not issue.

In many MPP databases (databases that target reporting, e.g. Vertica) a primary key is optional.
So if you know your data and use cases, you can avoid primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

A table without duplicate rows *always has* at least one candidate key. We can pick one to declare via `PRIMARY KEY`; any others are via `UNIQUE NOT NULL`. (`UNIQUE NOT NULL` is the constraint that you get from a `PRIMARY KEY` declaration.) If you don't *tell* the DBMS about your candidate keys then it can't help you by, say, reducing errors by preventing duplicates or improving performance by implicitly defining an index on its columns.

It's not clear from your question how you record what setting given new & old values are for. If your columns are `siteId`, `setting`, `newValue`, `oldValue` & `changeDate` then your table has one candidate key, `(siteID, setting, changeDate)`. As the only candidate key, it is the primary key. If setting values identify the settings so that your columns are `siteId`, `newValue`, `oldValue` & `changeDate` then you have two candidate keys, `(siteID, newValue, changeDate)` and `(siteID, oldValue, changeDate)`. Each should get a `UNIQUE NOT NULL` constraint. One could be via a PRIMARY KEY declaration.

If you add another column of unique/surrogate/id values then the table has another candidate key. As before constrain all of them via a `UNIQUE NOT NULL` constraint, one of which can be expressed via `PRIMARY KEY`. There are reasons for adding such a unique/surrogate/id column, but it's not because there's no primary key unless the table would otherwise have duplicates rows.

Answer (score 1):

All *entity* tables should have a PK, not all tables. History/log tables typically do not have a PK because they represent *events*, not entities. (Rather, they don't need a PK. I've seen them defined with one (generally auto generated) but I have yet to see the value used in a query. As far as I've been able to tell, they are completely superfluous.)

What history and log tables *do* have is a timestamp field and a field representing what event took place. The rest of the record will have some kind of entity information, including the entity PK, and other data concerning the event -- like before and after values such as the OP specified.

The timestamp column will be indexed, along with the entity ID (so one may examine all events that took place on a specified entity over a time period) and/or the event ID (so one may examine all the entities on which a specified event took place over a time period). This all depends on the type of information needed from the table.

Comment: That really helps. I think the first paragraph gives the explanation to what I was confused about.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the schema like this

> {**SiteId,version**,Setting,Change date}

As, old setting you can find in previous version so keep the value on each version is fine.

Of course, you can also use change date to be a PK like below:

> {**SiteId,Change date**,Setting,}

If the date is include time and your scenario is allow this, using date and siteID is better.

Comment: What will happen if i don't have any primary key ? Will it affect me in this scenario in any way ?

Comment: You would lose all of the relationship between another table. Also, the perfermance would be slower.

Comment: i dont have any relationship with another table, since this is used for reporting and all the data required is present in this table by itself. Inserts happen once in a while and are going to be max 5 per day.

Comment: But it is really have no relationship? That means the table you would not make change on it forever.

Comment: It is no disadvanage when you add a PK on it... It also provide some checking to ensure your data correct.

Comment: @Loser You do not need to declare a primary key, foreign key or any other constraint in order to query. Constraints help prevent errors and (as you said) can help performance. If you want to declare a foreign key then you do need to declare the column set it references as PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE NOT NULL.